# Make limit variable depending on results?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query which I can select at least 10 items but I want the limit to grow according to an SQL condition.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 10
 --LIMIT more if 
(SELECT count(timestamp) FROM table WHERE timestamp IS NOT NULL) > 10
```

So that the query limit only grows if there is more non null timestamps, but if there is less, show at least 10 fields.

**Update**

My database does not have `DECLARE` ability.
Am I right in thinking this would have to be done with more than just SQL?

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to do?  Sample data and desired results are helpful.

Comment: What I am trying to do is display a list of users based on the timestamp, show 10 if the timestamps are empty, if not then show more than 10 users.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simply CASE

```
    DECLARE @limit INT;
    SET @limit = 0;
    SELECT TOP(@limit) *
    FROM table
    CASE 
    WHEN (SELECT count(timestamp) FROM table WHERE timestamp is not NULL) > 10 THEN @limit = 'yourValue' 
    ELSE @limit = 10,
    END,
```

Comment: Your query has an error, see it [run on sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24c3f/2)

Comment: I'm about to implement it.
I can't seem to USE declare :(

Comment: Another small issue, no case End?

Comment: Shouldn't the `WHERE` clause be `timestamp is not null` ?

Comment: yeah, i think limit is not recognized in sql you should use TOP statement, i will update my answer, try the script

Comment: Nothing works, top is undefined, Declarations are not allowed, I feel like I have a cave era DB. Is there a way to limit it without variables?